# Error response from daemon: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists/merged/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

Tags: docker-volume

Hi am trying to run the image which is pulled from the docker hub.Below is my docker-compose file code.Error is regarding the Volume mount if i tried to change any modifications unable to run project.

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./deployment/dev/Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: ${APP_NAME}_app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - app-network
```